# How Can I Find Value is Come From Keyboard or Barcoder Reader in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows Application in VB.NET.  I want to know if a value is entered by a user via the keyboard, or if it is coming from a barcode reader.  I want to store values that come from
the keyboard in a different database than the ones the come from the barcode reader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read input from a barcode scanner in vb.net without using a textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134126/how-to-read-input-from-a-barcode-scanner-in-vb-net-without-using-a-textbox)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

Get a barcode-scanner that is connected to a serial-port (raw serial device read by a COM port). As most barcode-scanners emulate keyboard strokes there is no way to directly distinguish a barcode scanner input from a keyboard input (see next option) without going low-level (see last update).

One connected to a serial port (or emulated one via USB as serial-ports are not so common anymore) gives you full control on where the input comes from.

**Option 2:**

Count number of chars typed by time. Barcode-scanners inject a sequence (line) pretty fast compared to typing. Measuring the time used in the textbox by counting key-presses (use CR+LF as a measure point as these are sent by the scanner as well) can give you one method to distinguish if a human is typing (unless there is one typing fast as f) or the content was injected. If timed-out just reject/clear the input.

In addition the checksum of the barcode (if you use one that contains that) can be used to do an extra validation in addition to time measurement.

(you can detect pasting by overriding the ctrl + v as in the next option).

**Option 3:**

Combine option 2 but instead of measure in the textbox tap into the ProcessCmdKey() function (by overriding it) and measure there if textbox has focus. This way you can first buffer input, measure time and if within a set time-out value, inject the line into the textbox.

**Option 4:**

This might be a good option as well:
http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/

**Option 5:** a non-technical approach -

Usability improvements: make it visually very clear that bar-codes must be entered with a scanner and not typed. I am including as an option as it is simple and if made correct also effective (there's no right answer of what is correct unfortunately).

Approached could include f.ex. a watermark in the textbox ("Don't type, scan!" or something in that order). Give it a different color, border, size etc. to distinguish it from normal textboxes, and have a help text associated and available at all time that improves clarity.